# Riesz representation theorem if field is $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the following fragments from Folland's book:

[image]

This seems to suggest that we are working over $\Bbb{C}$. Do we still have $M(X) \cong C_0(X)$ when we consider the vector spaces over $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, it also holds for vector spaces over $\mathbb R$. Usually, one considers spaces on $\mathbb C$ because it is more general and spectral theory works at its best if the field of your Banach spaces is complex.

Comment: But do we need complex measures or real measures then?

Comment: Real functionals correspond to real measures and vice versa.

Comment: @Yaddle Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe, just to give a more structured answer. What is well-known is that the map
$$ M(X) \to C_0(X)^\ast, \quad \mu \mapsto I_\mu$$
is an isometric isomorphism (and this is usually refered to as the Riesz representation therorem). However, aside from the obvious Banach space structure there is also a lattice structure that can be investigated.

The space $M(X)$ is a Banach lattice with positive cone given by $M(X)_+ = \{ \mu \in M(X) : \mu \geq 0 \}$, where $\mu \geq 0$ if $\mu(A) \geq 0$ for all measurable sets $A \subseteq X$. On the other hand, $C_0(X)$ is also a Banach lattice with positive cone given by $C_0(X)_+ = \{f \in C_0(X) : f \geq 0 \}$. Hence, so is its dual $C_0(X)'$, with positive cone $C_0(X)'_+ = \{\varphi \in C_0'(X) : \varphi \geq 0 \}$, where $\varphi \geq 0$ if $\varphi(f) \geq 0$ for all $f \in C_0(X)_+$.

Now your question basicly boils down to the question if $\mu \geq 0$ if and only if $I_\mu \geq 0$ since $\mu = \mu^+ - \mu^-$ for all real measures $\mu \in M(X)$, where $\mu^+ = \mu \vee 0$ and $\mu^- = -\mu \vee 0$. This is actually the case, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) for example. There are several different Riesz representation theorems of is lattice theoretic kind, see Chapter 14, Riesz Representation Theorems in "Infinite Dimensional
Analysis - A Hitchhiker’s Guide" of Aliprantis and Border for example.

Finally, it is also worthwhile to state that you can perform all proofs on the real version of $M(X)$ and $C_0(X)'$ with just the same arguments. So you obtain all results for real Banach lattices. Then the complex theorems show in a sense that the complexifications of $M(X; \mathbb R)$ and $C_0(X; \mathbb R)'$ are given by $M(X)$ and $C_0(X)'$ and that the isometry $I$ extends nicely to these complex spaces.

I hope things got more clear :-)